# How to rearrange report section at print time in ActiveReports?

Tags: activereports

I need to print the report footer before the group header/footer in ActiveReports 6. My code in report footer requires calculation from the group header/footer, so instead of moving all the controls to report header and do massive changes to code, I wonder if there's a quick way to just rearrange the page at print time.

I currently have:

- rhMain (reportheader) for report cover page
- gfVehicle (groupfooter) for detail on each vehicle, summary data is also calculated and stored here for each vehicle to be used in report summary
- rfMain (reportfooter) for report summary

What I need to be arranged:

- rhMain cover page
- rfMain summary page
- gfVehicle detail on each vehicle

What I have tried is move all the summary stuff to rhMain and during rfMain_format, I change the value of the controls in rhMain. This failed probably because rhMain is already rendered at this point.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to rearrange the sections during printing. The sections are designed to be rendered in a specific order and it cannot be changed. If you can provide some detailed information about your use case we may try suggesting some workaround. You can post your questions to ActiveReports [support forums](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/forum/reporting/activereports-8/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain your scenario so we can try to help based on it.   In general a report footer is nothing but a "group-footer" for the whole report (that is not bound, so would it help to replace the report-header/footer with an outside group header/footer.

Please include an image of what you're trying to do so we help further.

Issam Elbaytam 
Grapecity.